# How does Castalia inline variable declaration work in Delphi XE8?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am trying to use the inline variable declaration with Castalia [described here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Castalia_Overview).

Here's the excerpt in question from the link above:

> **Inline Variable Declaration**
>        Castalia provides inline variable declaration. In the main body of your code, you can declare variables and Castalia will
>   automatically add it to the variable declaration section of your
>   function or procedure as soon as you press the space bar, the
>   declaration you typed in the main body is replaced by a reference to
>   the variable.

However, it does not seem to work for me.  For example, if I press the space bar after `myVar: integer` in this code:

```
procedure test;
begin
  myVar: integer
end;
```

I do not get this automagically (actually nothing happens):

```
procedure test;
var
  myVar: integer;
begin
  myVar
end;
```

There does not seem to be any specific Castalia setting to enable/disable in **Castalia**->**Castalia Options** for inline variables and the Embarcadero document does not mention any setting either.

How does the Castalia inline variable declaration work?

Comment: Just as an FYI: you don't need Castalia's functionality for this. Typing `var` and hitting Ctrl+J will invoke the new variable template that's part of the IDE itself.

Comment: Kudos to @KenWhite for knowing the live template!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [How_to_Use_Inline_Variable_Declaration_(Castalia)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Use_Inline_Variable_Declaration_(Castalia)).

You need to write:

```
begin
  var myVar: Integer[space] 
end;
```

to get

```
var
  myVar: Integer;
begin
  myVar
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the "How To" links at the bottom of the Embarcadero document.  Ironically, I guess that an "inline" link in the section of the document that describes the feature would have been helpful!